# When i ping mydomain.com i reply from www.domain.com

Tags: dns, domain-name

When i ping mydomain.com, the reply that i get is from www.mydomain.com.

I enter domain.com in my chrome it redirect to www.mydomain.com
please help me remove www from my url

this is my reply:
    PING botmember.ir (185.166.239.147) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from www.botmember.ir (185.166.239.147): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 
    time=0.026 ms
    64 bytes from www.botmember.ir (185.166.239.147): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 
    time=0.025 ms
    64 bytes from www.botmember.ir (185.166.239.147): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 
    time=0.039 ms
    64 bytes from www.botmember.ir (185.166.239.147): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 
    time=0.021 ms

Comment: It's not a web address without "www." So that might be hard.

Comment: Also consider reading your post before posting to avoid confusion and misunderstandings. You state two different things in the title and body of the question.

Comment: @RustyMembers I disagree. There are plenty of websites without 'www', and even some sites where 'www.sitename.tld' and 'sitename.tld' lead to different pages. 'www' is a convention, not a requirement. In this case, I suspect a reverse DNS issue, although the Chrome redirect suggests the webserver is redirecting as well.

Comment: @barrycarter If they are not configured as “www” that would be Server side but honestly it’s not clear what your question is because the behavior you describe is as expected

Comment: The apparent change of name on ping comes from the reverse DNS name (PTR record) and is totally unrelated to what goes on with HTTP

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me remove *www* from my url.

This is occurring likely because you have your domain set to redirect to a *www* subdomain.

To fix this:

1. Log into your domain registrar account for your domain name.
2. Remove any entries for [www sub-domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgLIE.jpg).
3. Make certain your [basic domain has an IP address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNp6q.jpg) and is not a redirect.

**Redirecting www to non-www URLs**

If you decide you would like to use *www* as well, you can also redirect *www.mydomain.tld* to *mydomain.tld*   via Apache mod_rewrite (you must enable mod_rewrite first):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This can potentially be placed in an .htaccess file or as part of your normal site configuration.

*Note: This assumes there is an entry for a www subdomain with your registrar (you did not remove the example entry in Step 2 above).*